# How to type Numpad Enter, if there's no such key on the keyboard?

Tags: linux, xorg, kde4

I'm working with an ancient platform emulator, so sometimes I need to press `Numpad Enter`, but my notebook keyboard has no options for doing that. Is is possible to emulate `Numpad Enter` key somehow? I don't mind if the solution is clumsy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remap the keyboard using xmodmap. For example, to turn F12 into numpad enter, use this command:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 96 = KP_Enter'
```

You can find out the keycode of keys by starting `xev` and pressing them. The list of possible keysym values can be found in [keysymdef.h](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/xproto/tree/keysymdef.h). Omit the `XK_` prefix. The numpad keys start with `XK_KP_`.

Answer (score -1):

I would think that your laptop has 'fn' key and little blue numbers on keys; 7,8,9,u,i,o,j,k,l and m. these are your numeric 'key pad', But if it doesn't...

In KDE > YaST2 > there are several on screen keyboards typically used for 'other' languages and Accessibility situation. Kvkbd seems to be installed on my openSuSE / KDE systems by 'default' as I did not specifically install it. On the right edge of Kvkbd, there is a << arrow looking thing that will expand it and show the numeric keypad.
screenshot: of kvkbd:

[image]

Kicker > (in search, type) keyboard and you should see a list generate of all the keyboard related apps you have installed. If not, back to above, YaST2 and install one.

Comment: Tried, it sends usual `Enter`, not `Numpad Enter`.